# htaccess searching for files

Tags: .htaccess

I am having trouble with .htaccess and I am on ubuntu, the problem is, when I write an uri like this,

```
127.0.0.1/u
```

the .htaccess searches for a file and when It finds a file that starts with that letter, the uri changes directly to this,

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/u/?tab_id=u
```

But, it should be like this,

```
http://127.0.0.1/u
```

It happens beacuse there are files that start with u like, user-edit.php and user-login.php ....

when I write

```
http:://127.0.0.1/a
```

or any uri that does not match any file, it runs perfect, this is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([//a-zçöşığüA-ZÇÖŞİĞÜ0-9_-]+)$ tab.php?tab_id=$1 [QSA,L]
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
<files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
```

I searched a lot, but cannot find the solution, thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a MultiViews problem. Disable this by using

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: thank you very much it was killing me, god bless you, thank you